# finding the max number of consecutive days of absence for any person who has more than a specified number of days

Tags: sql, ssms

I am working on an absence report and am having a hard time figuring out how to obtain the number of consecutive days an employee has off anytime they have 6 or more absences consecutively. I am able to get the max number for the employee but if an employee has more than one instance of this occurring within the given start and end date parameters, this max number of absences will only give me the highest number of absences. The following data set shows what I mean:

```
  ClientID  EmplID   Date    AbsentFlag   NumOfDays  RowNum
      10    2587    2019-07-14     Y       1         4
      10    2587    2019-07-15     Y       2         5
      10    2587    2019-07-16     Y       3         6
      10    2587    2019-07-19     Y       4         7
      10    2587    2019-07-20     Y       5         8
      10    2587    2019-07-21     Y       6         9
      10    2587    2019-07-22     Y       7         10
      10    2587    2019-07-23     Y       8         11
      10    2587    2019-07-26     Y       9         12
      10    2587    2019-07-27     Y       10        13
      10    2587    2019-07-28     Y       11        14
      10    2587    2019-07-29     Y       12        15
      10    2587    2019-07-30     Y       13        16
      10    2587    2019-08-03     Y       1         17
      10    2587    2019-08-04     Y       2         18
      10    2587    2019-08-05     Y       3         19
      10    2587    2019-08-06     Y       4         20
      10    2587    2019-08-09     Y       5         21
      10    2587    2019-08-10     Y       6         22
      10    2587    2019-08-11     Y       7         23
      10    2587    2019-08-12     Y       8         24
      10    2587    2019-08-13     Y       9         25
```

This employee, for example, has 13 consecutive days of absence(more than 6), as well as 9 consecutive days of absence (more than 6). In my report, I need to include the first 6 dates of absence, as well as the total number of absences for each consecutive streak. So for the results, I would expect this:

```
 ClientID   EmplID   Days    Date1         Date2        Date3         Date4          Date5        Date6
    10      2587      13   2019-07-14    2019-07-15   2019-07-16    2019-07-19   2019-07-20    2019-07-21
    10      2587       9   2019-08-03    2019-08-04   2019-08-05    2019-08-06   2019-08-09    2019-08-10
```

Currently, I am getting this:

```
 ClientID   EmplID   Days    Date1         Date2        Date3         Date4          Date5        Date6
    10      2587      13   2019-07-14    2019-07-15   2019-07-16    2019-07-19   2019-07-20    2019-07-21
    10      2587      13   2019-08-03    2019-08-04   2019-08-05    2019-08-06   2019-08-09    2019-08-10
```

Let me know if I can provide anything else to help solve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify the first day of an absence using the different of a sequence from `numofdays`.  Then aggregate and filter:

```
select clientid, empid, max(days),
       max(case when numofdays = 1 then date end) as day_1,
       max(case when numofdays = 2 then date end) as day_2,
       max(case when numofdays = 3 then date end) as day_3,
       max(case when numofdays = 4 then date end) as day_4,
       max(case when numofdays = 5 then date end) as day_5,
       max(case when numofdays = 6 then date end) as day_6
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by clientid, empid order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by clientid, empid, (seqnum - numofdays)
having max(numofdays) >= 6
```